How to add an IK-FK snapping feature to a rig?
I've recently made IK-FK switch drivers for my rig experiment, but is there a way to add an IK-FK snapping function similar to that of a Rigify rig? In other words, I want to add some buttons to the UI that snap the IK chain to the FK bones' position and vice versa.

As you can see above, I have to pose the FK and IK bones separately when I switch to one or the other. Below is an example of the features I want to implement.

Notice how I can "snap" the IK chain to the FK bones and vice versa.

I want to add these functions to my rig. How can I do this?
This is the tutorial I followed to set up the drivers. I'm using Blender 4.1.0. I hope this wasn't too confusing. Here is my .blend file:
